# In-App Purchases register new product programmatically

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is there any way to register In-App product in iTunesConnect programmatically?
I'd like to have 20 products in my application, but it is so painful to create new 20 products in iTunesConnect. Is there any API which I can use to do this programmatically?

I tried to find any information in the Guideline but there is nothing about it there.

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to make them in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Probably, I should file a request for such API. I am sure it will be useful for many developers because creating In-App products such a pain, especially for testing

Answer (score -1):

No because your products have to be reviewed by apple before you can sell them.

Comment: I don't think it is a reason. I could register new product programmatically and apple can review it and only after review it would be available. Also for test environment you don't need Apple approval