# Add iap product manually(programmatically)to the existing product

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have created one reference IAP Product on iTunes connect, but I want to know if there is any way to add a new product or replace with new product name and price to an existing Product programmatically.

I am getting a number of products from Server side and there is a chance to increase the number of products in future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-App Purchases register new product programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239097/in-app-purchases-register-new-product-programmatically)

Comment: But I am not getting any way through that link as per My Understanding level, because I am new to this iap. could you explain me clearly?